# Javascript on touchstart event to trigger function

Tags: javascript

The javascript code below works on desktop, but the touch event doesn't trigger on mobile (at least on iPhone). Where is my error on this? Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
// Virtual Tour
// -----------------------------------

// Toggles Intro to Virtual Tour Sections
function activate(){
    document.getElementById("virtual-tour-intro").className += " hide";
    document.getElementById("virtual-tour").className += " show";
};

// Click and OnTouch Event Trigger
var VirtualTour = document.getElementById("activate-video")
    VirtualTour.addEventListener("mouseup", tapOrClick, false);
    VirtualTour.addEventListener("touchstart", tapOrClick, false);

function tapOrClick(event) {
   //handle tap or click.
    activate();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code submitted actually works. It's was WordPress code injections into the HTML that was causing it to fail. Problem resolved.